# Pushing routes to Navigator in react-native

Tags: routes, react-native, navigator

I'm having real difficulty understanding the Navigator component.
I have a preset set of routes

```
routes: [{
    name: 'settings'
}, {
    name: 'feed'
}, {
    name: 'matches'
}]
```

So the app begins on the Feed page and then you can go back and forth between the 3 routes using the NavigationBar [omitted from code for ease]

```
<Navigator initialRoute={config.routes[1]}
           initialRouteStack={config.routes}
           renderScene={this.renderScene}} />
```

Now, i want to introduce a new temporary route [kinda like in instagram/spotify]
So on the Feed route when you click 'show profile' it pushes a new route to the stack.

```
this.props.nav.push({
  name: 'profile',
  sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
})
```

Now, whats annoying is that this replaces the Matches route completely because when I pop this route to go back to Feed. The Match route has completely been erased.
I've looked at the API and i've tried using replace method etc but keep getting funky results.

See GIF below for better understanding.

Is this the correct way of using navigator, having a preset set of routes? I'm using jumpBack/jumpForward in NavigationBar to move between them, however i'm not able to have specific sceneConfigs for the preset routes. How do i go about doing that? for example, if i want settings route to FloatFromBottom?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: UPDATE: i've solved this issue by creating a custom NavigationBar component which reflects any route changes https://github.com/antigirl/ReactNativeGraphRoutes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the routestack in the first place. In my apps I encode all the scene transitions into the logic and continuously push and pop scenes into the stack.

I think using the `initialRouteStack` may not be sufficient for your usecase. Read http://devdocs.io/react_native/navigator

> push(route) - Navigate forward to a new scene, squashing any scenes that you could jumpForward to

so you see when you used `push` you destroyed the 3rd scene. Try restructuring your app to push and pop without predetermining the scenes.

You could also try adding the profile route as a 4th scene and transition between those.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if you take my use case for example, if you pop MATCHES and push PROFILE you'll notice lots of inconsistencies, not only in transitions but in the Navigation bar too 

ALSO popping scenes un-mounts them and it seems like really bad UX to not maintain user behaviour in previous scenes. Managing them in state is too much overhead too. 
Consider Instagram and Spotify, scroll around in 1 scene and transition to the next and go back to it, your scroll position and any interaction will be reserved. Unless you go off the main route.

Comment: your app routes are not a linear stack then. It's a graph. Does adding it as a 4th route and transitioning between them work? Also your profile route sounds perfect for a [modal](http://devdocs.io/react_native/modal) even though you don't have a hybrid app. The modal won't affect your routestack.

Comment: Thanks Harry, its not a linear route, the transitions within navigator do not work. I've tackled this problem now by making my own navigatorBar component. if anyone is interested

https://github.com/antigirl/ReactNativeGraphRoutes